# user login by user type in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this is my php to redirect my users into their profile page.

I've got an userlogin table in database.

their also usercategory field in that table.

its saying an **error22527**.

```
            include'connection.php';




            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbluser_login WHERE user_Email='$_POST[email]' AND user_Password='md5($_POST[password])'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            $usercategory = "SELECT user_Category FROM tbluser_login WHERE user_Email='$_POST[email]'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($usercategory);
            $result3 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);



            if ($result){
                if(mysql_num_rows($result)){

                    /*session_regenerate_id();*/

                    $login = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                    $_SESSION['SESS_username']= $login['user_Email'];

                    $_SESSION['SESS_usercategory'] = $login['user_Category'];

                    $_SESSION['SESS_pasword'] = $login['user_Password'];

                    session_write_close();

                    switch($result3[0]){

                        case 'Staff':
                        header("location: staff_profile.php");
                        break;

                        case 'Tutor':
                        header("location: tutor_profile.php");
                        break;

                        case 'Student':
                        header("location: student_profile.php");
                        break;

                        case 'Administrator':
                        header("location: admin_profile.php");
                        break;


                    }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo("error".error_reporting(E_ALL));
                        exit;
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Do google "mysql error22527" In google we trust, in google we believe, google is our all father.

Comment: You should improve the question. It's really vague and unprehendable.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo("error".error_reporting(E_ALL));
```

should be

```
echo("error".mysql_error());
```

Comment: An explanation of what's happened here: The error_reporting constants `E_NOTICE, E_ALL, E_STRICT`, etc are bitwise-OR combined integers and you're echoing out your error reporting setting (22527) instead of the `mysql_error()`.